# Правильно ли вызывать два метода объекта в разных потоках на java?

Tags: java, android, canvas

В SurfaceView создаётся объект с методами draw и update, а также два потока DrawThread (в потоке происходит рисование) и UpdateThread (всякие вычисления связанные с объектом). Такое допускается? 
Если нет, то каким образом разделить операции рисования и вычисления в разных потоках?

Answer (score 5):

В принципе, нет ничего страшного в том, если разные методы одного класса бегут в разных потоках. Единственное ограничение — это разделяемые *данные*: доступ у ним должен быть [синхронизирован](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).